# Filtering JSON objects with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file which contains unneeded values. I want to filter them by only selecting those I need, or deleting those I don't need. For example, I have this JSON file:

```
{
 { "id"    : "1",
   "key1"  : "val1",
   "key2"  : "val2",
   "name"  : "someone",
   "age"   : 39,
 },
 { "id"    : "1234",
   "key1"  : "val1",
   "key2"  : "val2",
   "name"  : "someone",
   "age"   : 39
},
{ "id"    : "4567",
  "key1"  : "val1",
  "key2"  : "val2",
  "name"  : "someone",
  "age"   : 60
 }
}
```

My aim is to get the following JSON, by deleting all key1 and key2 items recursively using a jq command:

```
{
 { "id"    : "1",
   "name"  : "someone",
   "age"   : 39,
 },
 { "id"    : "1234",
   "name"  : "someone",
   "age"   : 39
},
{ "id"    : "4567",
  "name"  : "someone",
  "age"   : 60
 }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: If this is supposed to be an **array** of objects, it should have square brackets: `[{…},{…},{…}]`.

Comment: @Ben B. You have edited this question changing all occurrences of `jq` to `JQuery` (which is something completely different). Based on OP @Chloe's previous questions (which so far were all regarding `jq`) I doubt that `JQuery` is intended here.

Comment: @chloe - Your Q states you have a JSON file, but the example you give is neither valid JSON nor valid as a stream of JSON entities.  Please fix.

Answer (score 2):

If the input is supposed to be an array of objects (then format it as `[{…},{…},{…}]`), you can use `map` to apply filters or a new formatting onto each element of the array.

Construct what you need ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WPomqDD9S-)):

```sh
jq 'map({id,name,age})'
```

Or remove what you don't need ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LUusoASVEm)):

```sh
jq 'map(del(.key1,.key2))'
```

Both produce:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "someone",
    "age": 39
  },
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "someone",
    "age": 39
  },
  {
    "id": "4567",
    "name": "someone",
    "age": 60
  }
]
```